# Why jetpack compose text colors looks different from the preview?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am new to Jetpack compose. I am following the tutorial and the problem is that according to the tutorial the text color is black on the preview as well as on the real device (in the tutorial)

[image]

on my preview I also see the color as black, however, when I run the app on my two different devices I see the color is white.

What am I missing here?

***UPD***

```
package com.example.composableexmp

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CornerSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.composableexmp.ui.theme.ComposableExmpTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApp {
                TopHeader()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyApp(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    ComposableExmpTheme {
        Surface(
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
        ) {
            content()
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun TopHeader(totalPerPerson: Double = 0.0) {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(150.dp)
            .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(corner = CornerSize(12.dp))),
        color = Color(color = 0xFFE9D7F7)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
             val total = "%.2f".format(totalPerPerson)

            Text(
                text = "Total Per Person",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5
            )

            Text(
                text = "$$total",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold
            )
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    ComposableExmpTheme {
        MyApp {
            Text(text = "Hello Again")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot to call the `composable theme function`, like `YourAppNameTheme { composables should go inside }`. If you can't identify if this is the problem, put some of your code here so we can analyze it better.

Comment: Are those two devices in Dark/Night mode? and can we see your code?

Comment: @ThalesIsidoro I added the code, however, anyway, the problem really was due to my device being on dark mode... I am not sure with this Material automatic adjustment if the result is something that I expect. I mean for example I did an application using a Material design approach, but if the user use dark mode, so app font colors look completely different like white and black color, don't you think so?

Comment: @YaMiN I added the code, however, anyway, the problem really was due to my device being on dark mode... I am not sure with this Material automatic adjustment if the result is something that I expect. I mean for example I did an application using a Material design approach, but if the user use dark mode, so app font colors look completely different like white and black color, don't you think so?

Comment: Check the `Colors.onSurface` in your `Theme.kt` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colors change based on your theme. You should inspect Theme.kt in ui.theme folder.

```
private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
    primary = Purple80,
    secondary = PurpleGrey80,
    tertiary = Pink80
)

private val LightColorScheme = lightColorScheme(
    primary = Purple40,
    secondary = PurpleGrey40,
    tertiary = Pink40

    /* Other default colors to override
    background = Color(0xFFFFFBFE),
    surface = Color(0xFFFFFBFE),
    onPrimary = Color.White,
    onSecondary = Color.White,
    onTertiary = Color.White,
    onBackground = Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
    onSurface = Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
    */
)
```

And how these colors are selected

```
@Composable
fun MyTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }
        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            (view.context as Activity).window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(view)?.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

On Surface is the color of the `Text` provided by `Surface`. Based on your theme it can be the values set to these colors.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i have only one color pallet, and still different colors for preview and device

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that perhaps your devices are below Android 12?

The generated `Composable` in `Theme.kt` has this signature

```
@Composable
fun ComposableExmpTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
…
```

Making the app use dynamic color scheme whenever available.

The IDE previews will appear using `dynamicDarkColorScheme(context)` and `dynamicLightColorScheme(context)`, somewhat simulating a behavior of Android 12+ devices. While your physical devices (if they have Android <12) use your `DarkColorScheme` and `LightColorScheme`.

For a quick fix, just use your theme as:

```
ComposableExmpTheme(dynamicColor = false) {
    …
}
```

Or see the code in `Theme.kt` and adjust it according to your needs.

---

Sadly, using `@Preview(apiLevel = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)` does nothing to the color scheme displayed in the preview.

Comment: thanks but you are wrong with apiLevel annotation, it works